# why does not my menu display the same line as the code?

Tags: html, css

I want to put the menu in line with the text logo. The menu when I write it, puts it down and does not put it in line with the logo. Can someone help me?

```css
nav{
    width: 1330px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

nav ul li{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Despre noi</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Servicii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cere ofertă</a></li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
```

Comment: Can you also share with us your HTML/CSS code for the logo?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.logo-cont {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     padding: 50px 0;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
}

 .logo-cont a {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .logo-cont a .logo {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     -ms-flex-negative: 0;
     flex-shrink: 0;
     background-image: url(../res/imgs/logo.svg);
     background-size: contain;
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 .logo-cont a .logo-text {
     font-size: 28px;
     color: #E9DFF7;
     font-weight: 800;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-align: end;
     -ms-flex-align: end;
     align-items: flex-end;
}
 .logo-cont a .logo-text .logo-dot {
     width: 8px;
     height: 8px;
     background-color: #8E3BEB;
     border-radius: 100%;
     margin-left: 3px;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
     transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```
nav{
 width: 1330px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

nav ul li{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

<nav>
 <span class="logo">Logo</span>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Despre noi</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Servicii</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cere ofertă</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PopoviciCosmin-Marian Just ensure that you name the classes properly than using the html tag names for styling.